# Crop camera view in libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, camera, libgdx

I'm making an Android game using LibGDX. I want to do something hard to explain but I'll try nonetheless.

Look at this camera view (it's from 3ds max): 
[image: 3D scene view]

I can get same exact view in LibGDX without any problems:

```
perspCam = new PerspectiveCamera(40, screenHeight, screenWidth * h / w);
perspCam.position.set(1, 6, 18f);
perspCam.lookAt(1, 3, -1f);
perspCam.update();
```

Now the tricky part. What I actually want to see in-game is part inside the red rectangle but filling the whole screen.

I have managed (using GlScissors) to make it look like this:

[image: clipped 3d view]
But I have no idea how to make it fit the whole screen.

```
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(Gdx.gl20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);    
Gdx.gl20.glScissor(0, 0, 450, 550);
modelBatch.render(instance);
modelBatch.flush();
Gdx.gl20.glDisable(Gdx.gl20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
modelBatch.end();
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using glScissor, you should change camera position.
Make it nearer and shift it sideways too. The exact coordinates can be calculated properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't work me, because it would change the perspective (I want to preserve the 90deg angle between sideline and half court line)